# Trying import a CSV and create new AD users: Need to concatenate two variables for the -name switch

Tags: powershell

So I have my CSV file that I am importing to create new AD users, and I'm trying to concatenate the **-name** attribute value so it's in the format below.

> lastname, firstname

```
<code>... | New-ADUser -name '($_."surname"), ($_."givenname")'
```

I know what I have here is wrong.  I've tried many different variations, all no good.  Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the -Name parameter allows pipeline binding by property name then you can do this:

```
... | New-ADUser -Name {$_.Surname + ", " + $_.GivenName}
```

If that parameter doesn't support pipeline binding then try this:

```
... | Foreach {New-ADUser -Name ($_.Surname + ", " + $_.GivenName)}
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh you the man!  It was the 2nd one that did it for me.  Appreciate the help!